# Python - encoding/decoding Windows vs Linux

Tags: python-2.7, encoding

Having this line of code:

```
print "S\x00A\x00V\x00A"
```

produces different output. On Windows:

```
S A V A
```

and on Linux:

```
SAVA
```

What is the difference between the the 2 platform and what can I do to remove the whitespaces from the Windows case?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is at the terminal level.

Windows `cmd` prints the zero-char as empty whereas your Linux terminal doesn't print it.

Note that in PyScripter console or PyCrust console (wx-based) you only get `S` (probably because the zero is seen as a line-termination char). So it's definitely not portable :)

To get rid of it just perform a `replace`:

```
print("S\x00A\x00V\x00A".replace("\x00",""))
```